# How to implement checkout for headless iOS app using BigCommerce

Tags: ios, swift, checkout, bigcommerce

We are building a headless iOS app using BC server-to-server APIs as backend. So far we have integrated with product, categories and cart APIs. Now we want to do the checkout.

I know we can use server-to-server Checkout API to do the complete checkout from our app. But for that, we need to do the PCI compliance(correct me if I am wrong). We don't have that much time to do the compliance. What I need to know is, if there is an option where we can redirect the user to the BigCommerce checkout page and complete the checkout there. 
If yes, please let me know how can I do that. Also, is that allowed in iOS, as per iOS guidelines and rules? I mean, will apple reject my app if I redirect the user to BigCommerce for checkout using the in-app browser.
If no, please suggest if there is any other option or we have to take the long route by doing our own PCI compliance.

Is it possible that I use some other payment gateway and don't receive payment through BigCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that building a checkout on top of the BC server-to-server Checkout/Payment APIs would put you in PCI scope, but that can still be a good option if you need complete control over the checkout presentation and want to keep the shopper in-app for the entire experience.

As an alternative, you can use the server-to-server Cart API to generate a redirect URL that will take the shopper to the BC checkout:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-cart-api/cart/createcartredirecturl

I'd look to the [Apple app store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines) as the best source of truth for whether that's an issue.

A third option is the BigCommerce [embedded checkout](https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-sdk-js/tree/133066b0304438aae59ec859ec131bc10941e96a/docs#embedcheckout), which is what the [BigCommerce for WordPress](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-for-wordpress/blob/89a998ff158b33a1d5a264b1affc60379823a1b4/assets/js/src/public/checkout/embedded-checkout.js) plugin uses to solve the problem of headless checkout. Embedded checkout generates an iframed version of the BC checkout on a remote platform, so you can keep the shopper in-app for the entire process, and the iframe means that it's PCI compliant out of the box. The embedded checkout is still brand new, so we don't have public-facing docs yet, but we can put you in touch with some early access resources if you get in touch through your partner manager.

Comment: Thanks for replying! If we decide to go with the 2nd option, where we use the cart API to generate the redirect URL and we use an in-app browser to open that redirect URL, then do we need to do anything for PCI compliance or as I am sending the user to Bigcommerce checkout, BigCommerce will take care of that?

Comment: If you are redirecting to the BigCommerce checkout page, the BigCommerce attestation of PCI compliance applies. More information linked here on how PCI responsibility would work across different types of integrations: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/developers-guide-headless#headless-commerce_pci-compliance